# How to stop cmd prompt from showing when I run my .exe file

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pyinstaller

I have a made a GUI in Python, which I have turned into an .exe file using pyInstaller 2.1. Every time I run the .exe file the Windows Command Prompt starts, then my GUI starts on top of it.

Is there a way to stop the cmd prompt from showing?

(This happens on both Win7 and Win8 (64-bit) machines)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

showing console seems to be the default behaviour.
you may change this via **-w, --windowed, --noconsole**

see here: http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/develop/project/doc/Manual.html